# why you can call a non-static method in the main method by creating an object? Java

Tags: java, static

I can create an object in the main method and call the other method with the object I created.

```
public class Obj{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Obj obj = new Obj();
    obj.yourNameIs();

    }

    void yourNameIs(){
    System.out.println("TY");
    }
}
```

However, i have to change `yourNameIs` method to static if I want to call it without creating an object.

```
public class Obj{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    yourNameIs();

    }

    static void yourNameIs(){
    System.out.println("TY");
    }
}
```

I understand you cannot call a non-static method in a static method in this case the `main` method. But why I can create an object in the main method and then I can call a non-static method such as `yourNameIs()`? I mean why I do not need to change `yourNameIs()` to static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-static method is associated with an instance of the class. Once you have an instance, you can call such methods from anywhere you like (subject to Java's [visibility rules](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaprotection.php)). The fact that `main()` is `static` makes no difference at all here.

Answer (score 2):

If you create an instance of a class, you can call any instance (i.e. non static) method for this isntance. It doesn't matter if the instance is created in a static method.